# Unable to install TESTNG through Eclipse Marketplace as well as through Maven dependency

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Trying to install TestNG through eclipse marketplace and using the url from [testng](http://testng.org), [bintray](https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/).

Error -
No repository found at [bintray](http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/).

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This (http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/.) link is expired and no more functioning. And the real struggle begins Because on [TestNG website](https://testng.org/doc/download.html) the same link has given for installing the TestNG and The [Eclipse marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse) install button also fails to install TestNG.

**Solution 1** -

Use the URL in the Install New Software wizard of eclipse -
The update site to install snapshot versions of the TestNG Eclipse plug-in is:

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site

**Tested for Eclipse version** -
[image]

Before installing TestNG there is No TestNG version -

[image]

---

**Solution 2**
*Installation Steps -*

**Step 1** - Go to this [TestNG github page](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse)
and download the zip of your choice of version (Here I used 6.14.XX)
Check that this Zip file contains `feature` and `plugin` folder.

**Step 2** - Go to Eclipse directory structure and locate the `dropin` folder -  [image]
Inside this folder create the folder with name - `testng-eclipse-6.14` and extract the content of downloaded zip file. Here in my case `6.14` is TestNG version I have downloaded. (Note- Do not add/keep anything in this folder except the only content of zip file downloaded, delete the downloaded zip file from this folder if extracted by copy pasting.)

After extracting and creating the folder this is how it looks like -

[image]

**Step 3** - Now start Eclipse if in case of already running restart it again, Then to verify the TestNG installation press CTRL+N or open New wizard and look for TestNG or Search for TestNG. It should be displayed as in below screens.

[image]

you can see the option to convert general java project to TestNG java project -

[image]